# WGET encountering 403 when trying to access filter - nginx

Tags: wget, curl

I'm trying to download some images from an asset folder of a site, that folder happens to be forbidden.

I've tried various suggestions online including a referrer flag for google.com and setting the user agent (both simple and verbose) but still the 403 remains.

I can access the image directly if I give wget the full path but was hopeful of finding a workaround so I can fire and forget.

Is this feasible at all?

The most simplest for of the command that I'm using is :

```
wget -r -np -U firefox http://sitename.com/subdir/forbiddenDir
```

and the response is:

```
Reusing existing connection to sitename.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-03-01 22:26:41 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

curl yields similar response.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what kind of image paths worked with wget, and when you say `download some images from an asset folder`, how do you decide which images to download, for example if images end in a certain number and you want to download number range 1 to 10, or some other pattern?

Comment: @user454038 hello, i know the exact filenames that I'm looking for but it'd also be great to just scoop up the whole dir and its contents.  ideally the pattern would be .* within that fodder :)

Comment: i see. well I dont know of a way to force a 403 denied folder to divulge its contents, but seems you have some knowledge of its contents to be able to pull off downloading filenames directly. Where did you find out the file paths, and is there any possibility to get or scrape the rest of the folder's contents, from this source (instead of trying to list a 403 denied directory)

Comment: @user454038 me neither which is now begging the question of 'how', part of the fun is finding out how to do something we shouldn't be able to. :)

Comment: @user454038 - I got the file names from the html source of a parent dir.

Comment: Can you post as much of the html source as you can, just to show what the file paths look like. and how exactly they are written in html. there might be a way to automatically extract. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about web server permissions, not linux-unix permissions.

Comment: @BinaryZebra isn't it also about the correct options to use within a tool such as `wget` or `curl`? In which case it remains on-topic for U&L

Comment: I'm voting to close it because it's about getting access to something that the owner of the website has denied you. Breaking through the permissions deliberately set by the site owner is not something [unix.se] should help with.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to list directory contents of `forbiddenDir`.

If the server does not allow listing contents of a particular directory, then you get [`403.14 Directory listing denied`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) error.

The answer is: no, you can't.